# Nuxt: How to execute external script after rerender only?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Nuxt/Vue: How to call an external script (hosted by a third party) after and only after the DOM has rerendered? On every route.

I'm using a script that adds elements to the dom, but the virtual dom doesn't match. So, once the script has added the elements, the virtual dom removes them all.

Adding a defer tag doesn't do anything, it just loads the script after the initial render, then the same thing happens with the rerender.

Presumably this problem is common using frameworks like this.

No errors messages — just a single flash of dom elements before rerender. This is the expected behavior with my current set up, but I'm looking (desperate) for a work around.

Comment: what script is it? If it  changes dom that affect vue the only would be to wrap it into vue

Answer (score 3):

First, you would make a plugin:

```
export default ({ app: { head, router, context } }, inject) => {
  head.scripts.push({
    src: 'http(s)://example.com/script.js'
    async: false,
    defer: true
  })
})
```

Then you would add the plugin to your `nuxt.config.js` in your `plugins: []` section:

```
plugins: [
  // ....
  { src: '~/plugins/script-injecter.js', ssr: false }
]
```

Now it will only be provided on page load, and with `async: false` and `defer: true`, it will only be executed once the page has finished loading.

Comment: What's the benefit of using a plugin here? why not just use the head option in nuxt.config.js file?

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki It's been almost 4 years since this was written, I think architecturally speaking you can still choose this method if you feel, otherwise, you can absolutely use the head.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `defer:true` when referencing the script in your `nuxt.config.js`.

[script defer attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp)

[defer in vue-meta](https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/api/#script)